# How to reverse NAT by destination name

Tags: iis, web-server, reverse-proxy, nat, port-forwarding

I have one public IP Address and two web server inside my LAN.

For example `10.0.0.1` and `10.0.0.2` are the local IP addresses of my Web servers. I have configured on my router NAT for port `80` to `10.0.0.1`.

I am just wondering if it is possible to reverse NAT in the router by name? If the request header is `test1.example` redirect to `10.0.0.1` and if it is `test2.example` redirect to `10.0.0.2`. Or can I do that at IIS level? I mean in the router redirect all 80 request to `10.0.0.1` and in the Webserver1 if the hostname is `test2.example` then redirect to `10.0.0.2`.

Comment: No, You cannot do layer 7 operations at layer 4. Get a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only firewall that I know that can do that is Sophis UTM, with the Web Application Firewall (waf) module.

You create a virtual web server for each real webserver in the firewall

https://community.sophos.com/kb/en-us/120454

and an answer there https://community.sophos.com/products/unified-threat-management/f/web-server-security/90829/web-application-firewall-reverse-proxy-support-multiple-domain-or-wildcard-domain

Answer (score 0):

As yagmoth555 stated, what you are looking for is a reverse proxy. You have many options available, such as web application firewalls or using nginx.

However, if you are most comfortable with IIS, you can install the URL rewrite module.

[The rewrite module includes a wizard with an option to configure reverse proxy rules.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5OH2.png)